# Data structure for storing pixels for camera linearization

Tags: java, data-structures, dictionary, interpolation

Given a point in the picture of the camera and knowing that it lies on the floor I need to calculate the (x,y) of the object with respect to the camera. For this I'm taking a picture of a chess board lying on the floor and then I half manually for each cell of the board calculate the pixel coordinates of the corners.

So now I have a map from some pixel coordinates to real coordinates. Now given some point in the picture I want to find the coordinates of the board's cell this pixel is found in, and then I can just use some interpolation to find the real coordinates.

The problem is finding the four corners, i.e. four closes pixels from the map to the given pixels. Is there any convinient data structure to store the map in, so that I can find the four corners faster then O(number of cells)?

I'm using Java and I'm pretty familiar with basic data structures and algorithms.

Comment: With [this approach](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/35416) you don't need the fields of the board, or a data structure to hold them. Knowing the four corners of the chess board is enough to undo the projection and compute the coordinates relative to that board.

Comment: The camera has quite a lot of distortion and I'm aiming for a good precision, so I decided to go brute force.